# the meaning of 'case' in this sentence

Tags: meaning, comparatives, paraphrasing

I don't understand the meaning of *case* in this sentence:

> That may be wise policy, but it will also create an impression that many more potential problems exist than is the case.

I also don't know how to explain the comparative *more ... than* in this sentence.

Please paraphrase it to improve my understanding.

Comment: Search for the idiom "to be the case": https://www.google.com/#q=define+to+be+the+case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Case** *noun*
>   1 An instance of a particular situation; an example of something occurring
>   [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/case)

In your sample sentence, *case* refers to the current situation. In particular, it refers to the number of (potential) problems that exist (now).

The comparative *more ... than* compares the following:

- the number of (potential) problems that the policy may imply; and
- the number of (potential) problems in the status quo, that is, without the policy.

Your sample sentence asserts that the first will appear to be greater than the second.